# FullCalendar Vuejs with resources

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I  am having an issue getting the resource timegrid to work. the code and errors are below its as if the plugin isn't loaded correctly. Open I've just been looking at this way to long and I'm missing something simple.

The code is to large to provide so I gave a screen shot of the calendar options. only thing not shown is the api call to load the events but it fails way before that stage.

**Error:**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'resourceOrder' of undefined
at ResourceDayTimeColsView.render (VM23193 660:83)

**Code:**

```
<FullCalendar  :options="calendarOptions">
                        <template v-slot:eventContent='arg' v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': arg.event.backgroundColor }">
                            <div class="event-wrapper" v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': arg.event.backgroundColor }" v-bind:class="{'pastEvent': arg.isPast}">
                                <b>{{ arg.timeText }}</b>
                                <span>{{ arg.event.title }}</span> 
                                <i class="forms-icon fas fa-file-signature" v-bind:class="linkedFormsClass(arg.event)" 
                                    v-if="arg.event.eventLinkedFormGroups != null && arg.event.eventLinkedFormGroups.length > 0"></i>
                                    
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </FullCalendar>
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to load the resource-common plugin and well - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/plugin-index

Comment: @ADyson I left that out because looking at the files for the packages the resource-timegrid already imports it. I did however try it (I'll try anything at this point) but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So npm says you should never have to run "npm cache clean" that it self-heals... That is not the case and even putting the correct versions in I still got incompatible versions!

I suspect this is because of branch changing and the package folder not being synced by git (ignore file) so switching doesn't technically force a change it just updates the package file. Most of the time works fine but not this time.

Comment: I face the same problem. What did you do exactly to solve the problem ? Remove and install again all fullcalendar packages ?

Comment: @Pete_Gore All you need to do is run the command "npm cache clean" then do "npm install"